# Demanding Page Numbering on Header and Footer

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

Hi I want to ask about this demanding page numbering from my university, is this even possible in LaTeX?

I use `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}` for my document.

- Page Number is in the center footer if the page is the beginning of new chapter
- Page Number is in the right header if the page number is odd
- Page Number is in the left header if the page number is even

Would be appreciate it if you give me reference how to do it

Thank you.

Comment: Which document class do you currently use?

Comment: The fancyhdr package might be interesting.

Comment: `\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}` should help get you started.

Comment: hi leandriis I use `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}` for documentClass, will it work?

Comment: Without the twoside class option it will not work.

Comment: Okay, thanks, appreciate it